# displaying limited number of records in rails 3 (not pagination)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering if there is a way to display only a limited number of records from database.

I have a div container in index page called "Last items" and they are only 6 items and I did that using this code

```
@cars = Car.order('created_at desc').paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 6
```

and on the page itself I just removed the paginations so in the result I have 6 last added cars. But using this code means that it has to search all records and display only last 6 but would much better if it will stop searching records when it get's to the latest 6th record.

On the same page I have "special offer"

```
@cars_see_special = Car.where(:special => "yes").order('rand()').paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 1
```

that also have to search all records and return a random one in the view and as the paginate is set up to 1 it will be only one record diplayed, but again, this things increase the site loading cause it has to go through all records to display only 6 or 1.

If there is some more info you need, just let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rails' limit query:

```
@cars = Car.order('created_at desc').limit(6)
```

Comment: yes, much better and less server requests. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Create a model level finder, something like:

```
class Car ActiveRecord::Base
  def recent6
    where :limit => 6, :order => 'created_at desc'
  end
end
```

or

```
class Car ActiveRecord::Base
  def recents(how_many)
    where :limit => how_many, :order => 'created_at desc'
  end
end
```

Then you can test it at the model level and keep your controllers thin :)

Comment: I'll have to try this way too.. as I understand it, the difference between the sossborn's solution and yours is the "less code in controller", am I right?

Comment: yes, although it's really about much more than (just) less code, it's also about things like: controllers stay with basic RESTful actions without modification, models become the heart of the system for all of this business logic and there is one place to look, queries against models that all share the same characteristics (such as order) can have these properties applied once at the model level - good because the code is not repeated (yuch) and you are using a DRY (Don't repeat Yourself - a Rails mantra) approach and also the rule is applied for new objects automatically.

Comment: Keep enough of this in your models and you'll find your unit testing stays there most of the time.

Comment: You can also control eager loading (i.e. information from associated records) with includes, which addresses the n+1 'problem' (as opposed to lazy loading, for examples when multiple finders are chained but the query is not executed until actually needed).

Comment: all right.. a very good solution and a nice lesson for this day. Thank you too very much for help.